# Explicit wait Selenium Webdriver for element in hand

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver over C# and I am using page object module. Now I need a syntax to use in explicit wait given that I already have the webelement in hand.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Passwd")]
public IWebElement Password {get;set;}

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "signIn")]
public IWebElement Signin { get; set; }
```

I need to wait until I find the Element Password.

Before using this module I was using :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
```

Now I need to use the Element in hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using [`ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable_1.htm) which would accept `IWebElement` as well as input and would wait until element is visible and enable as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(Password));
```

Comment: ElementToBeClickable is not accepted in Expected conditions. it gives......... 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions' does not contain a definition for 'ElementToBeClickable

Comment: You can see this link for c# docs, https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable_1.htm it  is supported by `ExpectedConditions`. I'm strange why are you getting error

Comment: What version of the selenium are you using??

Comment: Selenium Webdriver 2.44.0

Comment: That's why you're in trouble, you should upgrade your selenium version to 2.48.1.0 or above because it supports from version 2.48.1.0. it clearly mentioned on the provided links docs thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this helps

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

wait.Until(driver => Password.Displayed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an explicit wait and wait for `Password.Displayed` to be true:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Passwd")]
public IWebElement Password {get;set;}

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "signIn")]
public IWebElement Signin { get; set; }

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(Password.Displayed);
```

Full disclosure, I found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/xdFsocNMSNc

Answer (score 0):

The expected conditions methods take `By` as their argument and you want to use `ElementIsVisible`, i.e. the below should work:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Passwd")));
```