# Selenium - asserts are not checked correctly

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having problem with tests which were written in Selenium + C#. Example test:

```
    [Test]
    [Description("Cashback - Checks whether Cashback field shows correct amount of money which needs to be returned to the customer")]
    public void CachbackFieldIsCountedCorrectly()
    {
        LoginHelpers.LogInUser(driver);

        var mainPosPage = new MainPosPage(driver);
        mainPosPage.WorkSpaceComponent.ProductGalleryComponent.LatteElement.Click();
        mainPosPage.PaymentOptionsComponent.CashElement.Click();
        mainPosPage.WorkSpaceComponent.CashNumpadComponent.Click(5).Click(0).Click(0).Click(NumpadCommand.Pay);

        Assert.AreEqual("Cashback 1.50", mainPosPage.StickyInfoComponent.CashbackElement.Text);
        Assert.IsNotNull(mainPosPage.StickyInfoComponent.CashbackElement);
        Assert.AreEqual("0.00€", mainPosPage.BasketComponent.TotalAmountElement.Text);
        Assert.IsTrue(mainPosPage.CategoriesBarComponent.IsTopCategoryElementActive, "POS was not redirected to the 'TOP' category");
        Assert.IsTrue(mainPosPage.BasketComponent.IsBasketEmpty, "Basket is not cleared after successfull payment");

Xpath selector: private static readonly By totalAmountLocator = By.XPath("//div[@class='total-container']//div[2]");
```

I've implemented Page object model and everything is fine on my local pc, tests are marked as passed, each of them. However, since I've implemented CI and nightly builds/tests from virtual machine I'm facing problem with assertion. It seems that assertion is done "immediately" right after second phase (act) and result is marked as failed even if I know it works correctly when I'm running it locally (not with VSTS). Erros like:

```
String lengths are both 5. Strings differ at index 0.
Expected: "0.00€"
But was: "3.50€"
-----------^

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class = 'sticky-info error']"}
(Session info: content shell=)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I need to somehow "force" my test to wait for the assertion, I've tried with both: implicit and thread.sleep ways but it's still broken.

How asserts should be written in correct way? Right now I'm receiving information that: "element was not founded...". Even thought, I know it works correctly...

Comment: You didn't post the exact error message, but "element was not found" sounds like webdriver exception, nothing to do with the assertions. Post the full stack trace and the relevant code (if the error occurs in another place).

Comment: I've added example errors

Comment: The error message is clear, `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class = 'sticky-info error']"}`. Add some [explicit wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975256/explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-for-element-in-hand) when looking for it.

Comment: Or share the HTML of `"//div[@class = 'sticky-info error']` element

Comment: It works correctly on my local machine, the whole test set is marked as passed. The problem is when it's triggered by VSTS CI process. The problem appears with somehow running "to fast", asserts are performed before "act" phase is done... more less

Comment: that's xpath , right ? Just share the HTML or write css selector or any other locator if possible.

Comment: Sorry for being late with answer, the fact is that - it's not locator problem - it's problem with assertion flow. Is this a good way of writing test when I'm doing act and for example next.. 5 asserts? Currently my two are tests failing: it's build like: act - assert - act - assert. Should there be any implicit/ explicit waits between them? If I put e.g implicit wait, it will wait for every assert to be performed before closing the browser?